# How to solve Laravel Post Error 403 with ajax?

Tags: ajax, laravel-8, server-side

I want to insert some record into database table which is using server side mode. Im using laravel 8, php version 8.0.13, database mysql.

This is my Route

```
use App\Http\Controllers\JabatanController;

Route::resource('jabatan', JabatanController::class, [
'names' => [
    'index' => 'jabatan.list',
    'store' => 'jabatan.store',
]]);
//dd($request->all());
```

My view

```
<button type="button" id="tambah-jabatan" class="btn btn-primary float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_tambah">
        Tambah Jabatan
    </button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_tambah" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTambahLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTambahLabel">Tambah Data Jabatan</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <!-- mb -->
                <div class=" mb-3">
                    <label for="jabatan">Jabatan</label>
                    <input type="text" name="jabatan" class="form-control" id="jabatan" placeholder="Masukkan Jabatan disini" value="" required>
                </div>
                <!-- /mb -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="close" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="save-jabatan" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Controllers

```
public function store(StoreJabatanRequest $request)
{
    $data = Jabatan::updateOrCreate([
        'jabatan' => $request->jabatan,
    ]);
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

My Model

```
class Jabatan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "jabatans";
    protected $fillable = [
        'jabatan'
    ];
}
```

some ajax script in my main view

```
<script>
    $('#save-jabatan').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('jabatan.store')}}",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                jabatan: $('#jabatan').val(),
                "_token": "{{csrf_token()}}"
            },
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res.data);
                alert(res.text)
                $('#close').click()
                $('#tb_jabatan').DataTable().ajax.reload()
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseJSON.text)
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

and when im check on inspect i got this error

> POST http://localhost:8000/jabatan 403 (Forbidden)

there's any suggestion?

Answer (score -2):

Ok, so in my case the problem is on my App\Http\Request\StoreJabatanRequest.php

```
class StoreJabatanRequest extends FormRequest;

public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'jabatan' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: 403 is routing related issue. How you solve it by Custom Request. 
How was the CustomRequest before. And what changes you made?